# Angular2 Output/emit() not working

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular2-directives

For the life of me I cannot figure out why I cannot either emit or capture some data. The `toggleNavigation()` fires, but I'm not sure if the `.emit()` is actually working.

Eventually I want to collapse and expand the navigation, but for now I just want to understand how to send data from the `navigation.component` to the `app.component`.

[Here is a Plunker link](https://plnkr.co/edit/wdZ8fRxXPkC1ik3y5NSA)

**app.component**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { PasNavigationComponent } from './shared/index';

@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    selector: 'pas-app',
    template: `
          <pas-navigation 
            (toggle)="toggleNavigation($event);">
          </pas-navigation>

          <section id="pas-wrapper">
              <pas-dashboard></pas-dashboard>
          </section>              
    `,
    directives: [PasNavigationComponent]
})

export class AppComponent {
    toggleNavigation(data) {
    console.log('event', data);
    }
}
```

**pas-navigation.component**

```
import { Component, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    selector: 'pas-navigation',
    template: `
        <nav>
            <div class="navigation-header">
                <i class="fa fa-bars" (click)="toggleNavigation()"></i>
            </div>
        </nav>
    `
    })

export class PasNavigationComponent {

    @Output('toggle') navToggle = new EventEmitter();

    toggleNavigation() {  
        this.navToggle.emit('my data to emit');
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

I added Pankaj Parkar's suggestions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You just need to specify `$event` parameter on method, so whatever emitted on  `navToggle` output value, that data will be available inside AppComponent `'s`toggleNavigation`method`$event` parameter.

```
<pas-navigation 
    (toggle)="toggleNavigation($event);">
</pas-navigation>
```

**AppComponent**

```
toggleNavigation(data) {
   // you can get emitted data here by `pas-navigation` component
   console.log('event', data);
}
```

[**Forked Plunkr**](https://plnkr.co/edit/JIbFcKnyInllPxXr3cSu?p=preview)

Comment: I can't believe I left the `$event` out. I made the corrections and still nothing. I did notice that the `console.log()` doesn't fire off. So i'm thinking the `(toggle)="toggleNavigation($event)` is not firing.

Comment: @Mike could you find attached plunkr in my answer, Thanks :)